# Can OpenFileDialog receive filename *.*?

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I want to use `OpenFileDialog` as selecting file with expression( *.*  or *.zip) On **File Name EditBox.**

Do I have to override `OpenFileDialog` ?  if then, please give me a tip about it.

At now,  If I put file name as  *.*   and click 'open' ,  the OpenFileDialog doesn't return anything.

Sorry about my poor English.

[image]

Comment: What are you using? Winforms or WPF?

Comment: @sunglim Could you perhaps try to improve the question. There's a lot of confusion as to what exactly you mean.

Comment: yep. I uploaded a pic. I hope this picture help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want with `OpenFileDialog`. It wraps up the common Windows component which has special treatment for file names that contain wildcards. Those are interpreted as filters for the file list view.

Comment: I uploaded a pic related to my question.

Comment: In that case I understand you correctly and my answer stands.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you want to filter the possible file types of the file dialog. You can do that like this:

```
myOpenFileDialog.Filter = "Zip Files|*.zip";
```

If you want to allow several file types, you can just extend the list with several |'s

```
myOpenFileDialog.Filter = "Zip Files|*.zip|All Files|*.*";
```

Comment: What you say is all perfectly true but that's not what the question asks. The question is about allowing the user to enter *.zip, say, in the File name text box and have that value returned when the dialog is closed.

Comment: sorry my question doesn't mean that. I just want to select files with asterisk.asterisk instead of filename on file name box on OpenFileDialog

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You assume incorrectly. I do that all the time. You can for example enter `*.*` to see all files if the list is filtered. EDIT: Does the OP perhaps means multiple files based on a wildcard?

Comment: @Leppie No, I don't think so. I regularly use wildcard notation to filter in the file dialog. What OP wants to do is to click Open button and have FileName == "*.zip" returned to the calling code. At least that's my reading of the question but I'm getting less and less sure of myself!